# What happens to the high 8 bit register when popping from stack register?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, cpu-registers, callstack

When popping from a stack register like this: `pop bx` in an x86_64 system running in 16 bit mode, what happens to the `bh` register because when I try to access the `bh` register from there, it returns nothing. But when accessing the `bl` register, I get the value that I pushed onto the register.
My code:

```
mov ah, 0x0e

mov bp, 0x8000
mov sp, bp

push 'A'
push 'B'

pop bx
mov al, bl
int 0x10
```

But say I put the `bh` register instead of `bl` in the second to last line, I get nothing returned.

Comment: This may be a x86_64 system, but this is code run in 16 bit real mode with BIOS interrupts, right?

Comment: @MatteoItalia yes, I am running in 16 bit real mode using BIOS interrupts. I have a boot sector running the code on QEMU.

Comment: `push` in 16-bit mode always pushes a word.  So your `push 'B'` extends the constant `'B' (0x42)` to a 16-bit word, `0x0042`, and pushes that.  And that's what you end up with in `BX`, with `0x42` as the low byte in `bl` and `0x00` as the high byte in `bh`.  Note your `push 'A'` is just left on the stack.  You can't combine two bytes into one word with this method.

Comment: @Damako that's very relevant information (in facts, the fact that the system is x86_64 is not really relevant, as it's emulating a very fast 16 bit machine), I'm adding it to the post and adjusting the tags.

Comment: So with `mov al, bh` you are outputting character 0 which of course is not visible.  Note also that according to http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0106.htm you need to fill `bh` with the graphics page to use; just by luck here it happens to be 0 which presumably is already the active page.

Comment: Your whole push / pop stuff is equivalent to `mov bx, 'B'` as far as what happens to EBX/RBX, merging a new 16-bit value into the bottom of the full register.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thank you, that answered my question...

Comment: Zero is not nothing!  Registers always hold some value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `pop bx` writes the current word (16 bit) to bx, bh is overwritten by the upper byte of that word.
In your case you are pushing 'B' onto the stack which is extendet to be 0x0042 instead of just 0x42 so it has the length of a word.
If you then `pop bx` it will write 0x0042 ((word) 'H') into `bx` which will write 0x00 into `bh` and 0x42 into `bl`.